# How to evaluate the following limit? $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n^2+(-1)^n}-n.$

Tags: calculus, limits

I can't cancel the root but if I imagine endlessly large number instead of $n$ it seems like sometimes the limit will be $\sim1$ and sometimes $\sim(-1)$ which means it has no clear limit, but how can I prove it?  $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\sqrt{n^2+(-1)^n}-n\right).$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\begin{align*}\sqrt{n^2+(-1)^n}-n&=\frac{\left(\sqrt{n^2+(-1)^n}-n\right)\left(\sqrt{n^2+(-1)^n}+n\right)}{\sqrt{n^2+(-1)^n}+n}\\&=\frac{n^2+(-1)^n-n^2}{\sqrt{n^2+(-1)^n}+n}\\&=\frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n^2+(-1)^n}+n}\to 0\end{align*}$$ as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: which formula did you use at the start?  and why is the last part -> 0? cause my problem is that im not sure how to find the limit of $\sqrt{n^2 + (-1)^n} + n$

Comment: I used the formula $$(a-b)(a+b)=a^2-b^2$$. $a+b$ is the conjugate of $a-b$ and multiplying with it you get rid of the square root. Now for your second question $(-1)^n$ goes to either $-1$ or $+1$ as $n$ goes to infinity but that is not a problem because the rest of the term goes straight up to $+\infty$ and $\pm1$ does not make any difference. To see this more clearly factor out $n$ to obtain $$n\left(\sqrt{1+\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2}}+1\right)$$ Now $n$ goes straight up to infinity but $(-1)^n$ goes to zero oscillating from - to + but that is not important since in either cases it goes to zero.

Answer (score 3):

Could you not say $$\sqrt{n^2-1}\leq\sqrt{n^2+(-1)^n} \leq \sqrt{n^2+1}$$ 
To prove the higher limit, multiply by the conjugate:
$$\sqrt{n^2+1}-n = \frac{(\sqrt{n^2+1}-n)(\sqrt{n^2+1}+n)}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}= \frac{n^2-n^2+1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}$$
The limit of 
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n}$$ as n tends to infinity is 0. A similar argument can be shown for the lower bound. Therefore the original limit converges to 0 also by the sandwich theorem.

Comment: which means $\sqrt{n^2 + (-1)^n}$ is infinite but how "much" infinite is it? if i reduce -n (-> $-\infty$) will it still be infinite?

Comment: No i mean you can bound it above and below then if you can prove that these two converge to the same limit, the original limit must converge to the same limit

Comment: Yea $\sqrt{n^2 - 1}$ goes to infinite as well as $\sqrt{n^2 + 1}$ which means that $\sqrt{n^2 + (-1)^n}$ must go to infinite as well, so now I know that it goes to infinite which helps me but Im not sure how "strong" is that infinite is it equal to $-n$ infinite power?

Comment: I'll prove the higher limit then the other one is similar:

Comment: Ok I think i got it thanks